# run javascript in Ruby on Windows

Tags: javascript, ruby, v8, execjs, therubyracer

Does someone know how to run javascript (jscript would be fine also) in Ruby on a windows machine ? execjs, V8 and therubyracer don't seem to be available for windows..
I know how to run javascript outside Ruby.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but if you have a modern CPU with VT-x, install VirtualBox/Ubuntu and you have full power of Linux at your disposal (it works without VT-x too, only slower).

Comment: @Victor and what then ? do you make programs for your own to run in a virtual box ? once complete a program needs to be distributed and i only need to distribute to windows clients

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to their [Github](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs/), ExecJS is in fact available for Microsoft Windows.  It uses Microsoft Windows Script Host (JScript).

Comment: you are right, just discovered at my home pc that it runs there, must have been an issue at my work pc

Comment: I know this is and old thread.  These days Windows Script Host is typically disabled on business PCs by policy for security reasons.  ExecJS doesn't find it and fails.